# How to edit data when combining angularjs and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

I'm a beginner in the AngularJs and MongoDb world (i started learning today!!)

Actually i'm trying to do something very basic : Display a list of record, with an add button and a edit link with each record.

I'm using this lib https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab to connect to mongoweb.

Actually my data is displayed, when i try to add a record it works, but the problem is when i try to display the edit form!

Here is my index.html file, in which i display the data with a form to add a record and with the edit links :

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="team in teams">
            {{team.name}} 
            {{team.description}}
            <a href="edit.html?id={{team._id.$oid}}">edit</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form ng-submit="addTeam()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="team.name"  size="30" placeholder="add new team here">
        <input type="text" ng-model="team.description"  size="30" placeholder="add new team here">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
      </form>
</div>
```

And here is my edit.html code, which displays an edit form :

```
<div ng-controller="EditCtrl">

    <form ng-submit="editTeam()">
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="team.name"  size="30" placeholder="edit team here">
        <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="team.description"  size="30" placeholder="edit team here">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="validate edit">
      </form>
</div>
```

And finally my js code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['mongolabResource']);

app.constant('API_KEY', '____________________________');
app.constant('DB_NAME', 'groups');

app.factory('Teams', function ($mongolabResource) {
    return $mongolabResource('teams');
});

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, Teams) {
    $scope.teams = Teams.query();
    $scope.addTeam = function() {
        varteam = {
            name: $scope.team.name, 
            description: $scope.team.description
        };
        $scope.teams.push(varteam);
        Teams.save($scope.team);
        $scope.team.name = '';
        $scope.team.description = '';
    };

});

app.controller('EditCtrl', function ($scope, Teams) {
    //????????
});
```

My AppCtrl works perfecty, it displays the data w add records perfectly.

Now i want to add the js code for the edit, but i don't even know form where to start ? how do i a get the id parameter in the url ? how do i tell the view to fill out the form fields from the values from the database ? And finally how do i update the databse.

I know that i asked a lot of question but i'm really lost! thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tutoring

Comment: i don't understand ? What's the problem with my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are of course many possible solutions.

One solution is to use angularjs routing. See http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 for a tutorial.

Basically replace your ul list with something like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="team in teams">
        {{team.name}} 
        {{team.description}}
        <a href="#teams/{{team._id.$oid}}">edit</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can create a route that responde to your url:

```
yourApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/teams', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/team-list.html',
        controller: 'TeamListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/teams/:teamId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/team-detail.html',
        controller: 'TeamDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/teams'
      });
  }]);
```

In this way from the detail controller (that will replace your EditCtrl) you can access the id parameter using: `$routeParams.teamId`

Anyway I suggest to study well all the tutorials for a better overview.

Comment: So i'm obliged to put everything in the same file ? i can't use the edit.html file ?

Comment: You can use multiple files. In my example I have 2 files: team-list.html and team-detail.html . See the `templateUrl` property.